# How to make dynamic router management in CI 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my website I need to customise the url ,

I done it some way ,everything is working fine .I got what I need ,but I want to do it in  a proper way .

Below is my code

```html
$route['admin/lessons'] = 'admin/admin/lessons';

$route['admin/lesson_mgmt'] = 'admin/admin/lesson_mgmt';

$route['admin/labs'] = 'admin/admin/labs';

$route['admin/tools'] = 'admin/admin/tools';
```

Here in this way I am managing the custom url section .

I want to make this url dynamic so that ,the code will not be longer ,there are other section .

If i will do it in this way ,I have to write a lot .

Here i want to replace everything in a single line.

Can anyone suggest me anything ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

In your `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['admin/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = 'admin/admin/$1';
```

Hope it will work fine..

In above code.. `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` this is regular expression having combination of one or more alphanumeric characters(alphabets+numbers).If route gets `admin/characters`...it redirect to `admin/admin/characters`.

Comment: ya its working , thank you .

Can you please explain me more.?

Comment: Yes got everything ...thanx again